# $f(x)=\sum_{r=1}^{2021} \frac{r}{rx^2-1},\;F(x)=\int f(x)\;dx,\; g(x)=\sum_{r=1}^{2022} \tan\bigg(\frac{\pi r x}{2022}\bigg),\; G(x)=\int g(x)dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{r=1}^{2021} \frac{r}{rx^2-1},\;F(x)=\int f(x)\;dx,\; g(x)=\sum_{r=1}^{2022} \tan\bigg(\frac{\pi r x}{2022}\bigg),\; G(x)=\int g(x)dx.$$

$A_r=\{x \;|\; f(x)=r, r\in \mathbb R,\; x\in (-1,1)\},\;$ $B_r=\{y \;| \;g(y)=r, r\in \mathbb R,\; y\in (-1,1)\}$

$1.$ Value of $n(A_1)+n(B_2)$ is

(A) $6060$

(B) $6062$

(C) $6064$

(D) N.O.T.

Note: Where $n(A_1)$ denotes number of elements in set $A_1$

I don't know how to evaluate $f(x).$ Any hint will be appreciated.

for $n(A_1)$ i tried to do $f(x)=1$ but i couldn't think further.

as suggested by @Jakobian, I am adding image of source question.
[image]

And I think $r$ in $A_r$ is different from $r$ used for $f(x)$

My main doubt is how we will find $f(x)$

Comment: This question contains a bunch of errors, can you please fix them all. First, what's the point of defining $F$ and $G$. Second, $A_r$ and $B_r$ depend on $r$, but $r$ is also variable of some, I presume, quantifier in those sets? What?

Comment: You don't really need to evaluate any $f(x)$ or $g(x)$.
Let $0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_m = 1$ be the poles of $f(x)$ in $(0,1]$. One each $(x_i,x_{i+1})$, $f(x)$ is monotonic decreasing from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$. So there is a unique root for $f(x) = 1$ in each $(x_i,x_i+1)$. Since $f(x)$ is even and  $< 0$ on $[0,x_1)$, this means....

Comment: @achillehui, Thanks but i didn't understood One each $(x_i, x_{i+1}), \; f(x)$ is monotonic from $\infty$ to $-\infty$.? can you please provide me it's answer so i can award Bounty to you.

Comment: Can you count the intersection points if each sum were to contain only one term? Or two or three terms each? Or one has 2, the other 3 terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very interesting question I guess it is from FIITJEE AITS , and you are preparing for IIT just like me ..

Numerical approach is the only feasible way to solve this question .

We have to find the no. of solutions to $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=2$.

let us take a function similar to $f(x)$ having only 1 term

$f_1(x)= \frac{1}{1-x^2} $ ; it has $0$  solution in $x \in (-1,1) $

$f_2(x)= \frac{1}{1-x^2}+\frac{2}{2-x^2} $ ; it has $2$  solution in $x \in (-1,1) $

$f_3(x)= \frac{1}{1-x^2}+\frac{2}{2-x^2}+\frac{3}{3-x^2} $ ; it has $4$  solution in $x \in (-1,1) $
...

Similarly

$f_n(x)= \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}{r-x^2} $ ; it has $2(n-1)$  solution in $x \in (-1,1) $

$hence, n(A)=4040$

Same can be done for finding number of solutions of $g(x)$ but there is one key point which has to be taken in consideration while solving for $g(x)$

here

$g_1(x)= tan(\pi x \frac{1}{1})$  has $2$ solutions in $x\in (-1,1)$

$g_2(x)= tan(\pi x \frac{1}{2})+ tan(\pi x \frac{2}{2})$ has $3$ solutions in $x\in (-1,1)$

$g_3(x)= tan(\pi x \frac{1}{2})+ tan(\pi x \frac{2}{3})+ tan(\pi x \frac{3}{3})$ has $4$ solutions in $x\in (-1,1)$

and
$g_n(x)= \sum_{r=1}^{n}tan(\pi x \frac{r}{n})$ has $n+1$ solutions in $x\in (-1,1)$

and hence $n(B)=2022+1=2023$

In order to find number of solutions use a rough plot of the graph
here is some reference.

[$f_4(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=solve%20Divide%5B1%2CPower%5Bx%2C2%5D-1%5D%2BDivide%5B2%2C2Power%5Bx%2C2%5D-1%5D%2BDivide%5B3%2C3Power%5Bx%2C2%5D-1%5D%2BDivide%5B4%2C4Power%5Bx%2C2%5D-1%5D%3D1) ; [$g_7(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=solve+Sum%5Btan%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bpix%2C7%5D+r+%5C%2841%29%2C%7Br%2C1%2C7%7D%5D+%3D+2+%5C%2844%29+-1%3Cx%3C1) .